# How do I retrieve an attributed string from UITextField?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitextfield, nsattributedstring

I am not getting the desired results when I run this program. What I am trying to build is an attributer program that gets text from the user in a UITextField, and when they click the Update button it shows the text in a UILabel above the textfield. Once i get that working i will add buttons to edit the text.

```
#import "TextChangerViewController.h"

@interface TextChangerViewController ()
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *textInput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *textOutput;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *updateButton;


@end

@implementation TextChangerViewController


- (void)updateText:(NSAttributedString *)input
{
    [self.textOutput setAttributedText:input];
}
- (IBAction)updateDisplayText:(UIButton *)sender
{

    [self updateText:[[NSAttributedString alloc]initWithString:self.textInput.text]];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming you are using IB. If you are not then please correct me.

A good and easy way to do this is to click on the textfield in IB and change its `Text` property:

[image]

Also **do this for your UILabel** the exact same way. Then in your methods:

```
- (void)updateText:(NSAttributedString *)input
{
    self.textOutput.attributedText = input;
}

- (IBAction)updateDisplayText:(UIButton *)sender
{
    [self updateText:self.textInput.attributedText];
}
```

You could just as easily combine this into one method (as I am sure you know) but I left them separate as with your example. Lastly, just verify all of your `IBOutlets` are correctly linked.